# http to www while preserving subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have the following rule in .htaccess to redirect from domain.tld to www.domain.tld and it's working fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when trying to access domain.tld/forum , I get redirected to www.domain.tld

How can I redirect all non-www to www while preserving whatever subfolder the visitor is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REQUEST_URI` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` will have full request URI rather than relative path (from current directory) captured in `$1`

Comment: Same behavior as the original code, domain.tld/forum redirects to www.domain.tld

Comment: Make sure this is very first rule in your htaccess. Clear your browser cache and test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled to see what `301` URLs are you getting.

Comment: Okay, I was using firefox until now, I tried with Chrome first and the rule was not working at all. The htaccess file is in the root directory, and since I never visited it but went to the forum directly, it wasn't redirecting to www. Now I've also added your code to another .htaccess inside /forum , and it's working fine. However, in firefox I am still being redirected from /forum to root. After clearing the cache, it's working fine. Is there any way to fix this without clearing cache? I was doing the modifications live and some users might now be trapped because of this.

Comment: Unfortunately caches are maintained in local browsers and you cannot force them to clean. It will take a while before browsers make a call to web server again and update the cache.